# Are dg-modules over a cofibrant dg-category cofibrant?

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-categories, dg-categories

Fix a commutative ring $k;$ all dg-categories will be dg-categories over $k.$ Throughout the question, I will be following the notation and conventions of Toën's "[The homotopy theory of dg-categories and derived Morita theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408337)." For a dg-category $C,$ let $[C]$ be the category whose objects are the same as the objects of $C,$ and whose morphisms are defined by $\operatorname{Hom}_{[C]}(X,Y) := H_0(C(X,Y)).$

Let $F : C\to D$ be a dg-functor between dg-categories, and recall that:

- $F$ is *quasi-fully faithful* if for all $X,Y\in C,$ $F_{X,Y} : C(X,Y)\to D(FX,FY)$ is a quasi isomorphism,
- $F$ is *quasi-essentially surjective* if $[F] : [C]\to [D]$ is essentially surjective,
- $F$ is a *quasi-equivalence* if it is quasi-fully faithful and quasi-essentially surjective.
- $F$ is a *fibration* if it satisfies the following two conditions:

1. For all $X,Y\in C,$ the morphism $F_{X,Y} : C(X,Y)\to D(FX,FY)$ is a fibration in the category $\mathsf{Ch}(k)$ of chain complexes over $k$ (i.e., a surjection), and
2. For all $X\in C,$ given any isomorphism $v : [F](X)\to Y'\in [D],$ there exists $Y\in C$ and an isomorphism $u : X\to Y$ in $[C]$ such that $[F](u) = v.$

Recall that there is a model structure on the category $\mathsf{dgCat}_k$ of dg-categories over $k$ and dg-functors between them, with fibrations as defined above, and with weak equivalences given by the quasi-equivalences.

For a dg-category $C,$ define also the dg-category $\widehat{C}$ to be the full sub-dg-category of $\mathsf{dgMod}_{C^{\textrm{op}}}$ consisting of the fibrant and cofibrant objects, where we define the fibrations and equivalences on $\mathsf{dgMod}_{C^{\textrm{op}}}$ to be the functors which are level-wise fibrations and equivalences in $\mathsf{Ch}(k).$

> My question is: suppose that $C$ is a cofibrant dg-category. Then are either of $\widehat{C}$ or $\mathsf{dgMod}_{C^{\textrm{op}}}$ cofibrant dg-categories?

First, it is easy to show that $C$ is cofibrant if and only if $C^{\textrm{op}}$ is. Using this observation, the only way I've thought of to get a map $F : \mathsf{dgMod}_{C}\to A$ (or $\widehat{C}$) lifting a functor $\mathsf{dgMod}_C\to B$ along a trivial fibration $A\to B$ is to use the Yoneda embedding
$$
\begin{align*}
h^{-}:C^{\textrm{op}}&\to \widehat{C}\\
X&\mapsto\left(\begin{array}{lll}
    h^X:&C&\to\mathsf{Ch}(k) \\
    &Y&\mapsto C(X,Y)
  \end{array}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
and write any dg-module $M$ as a colimit of representable functors $M\cong\varinjlim_i h^{X_i}$ to define
$$F(M) := \varinjlim_i G(X_i),$$
where $G : C^{\textrm{op}}\to A$ is a lift of the composite
$$C^{\textrm{op}}\to \mathsf{dgMod}_C\to B$$
along $A\to B.$

However, there are a few problems with the strategy: first, $A$ might not have colimits! Even if $A$ did have appropriate colimits, this would only define $F$ at the level of objects, and it seems that $A\to B$ would have to commute with colimits in order for this to be reasonable. Is there a way to salvage this strategy, and if not, is there another way to approach this?

---

**Edit:** To add my main goal in asking this, I am asking this as a follow-up to my [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370227/does-formation-of-the-derived-infty-category-preserve-pushouts) about showing that the derived infinity category commutes with taking pushouts. I received a nice answer there addressing the situation in the $\infty$-categorical situation, but I was hoping to find a proof of this in the case of dg-categories which didn't pass through the $\infty$-categorical language. The proof sketch I came up with required the category of dg-modules over a cofibrant dg-category/algebra to be cofibrant in order to compute the derived tensor products that arise.

Comment: You seem to have defined 'quasi-fully faithful ' twice. i suspect the second was intended to be  the definition of 'quasi-essentially surjective'!

Comment: @TimPorter Yes it was, thank you!

Comment: Is a dg-category equivalent (as an enriched category) to a cofibrant one again cofibrant? I'm not sure the main question makes much sense, unless the answer is "no". A priori it should depend on the choice of the category Set up to isomorphism, and not just up to equivalence.

Comment: Why do you want categories of dg-modules to be cofibrant in the first place?  What is the motivation behind wanting such a property?  I suspect we may have an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here.

Comment: @Dmitri I'm trying to find a more "elementary" (non-$\infty$-categorical) proof that $\mathsf{dgMod}_C\otimes^L\mathsf{dgMod}_{D}\simeq\mathsf{dgMod}_{C\otimes^L D}$, at least for $C$ and $D$ dg-algebras (I asked a different question about this and got a nice answer, but I wanted to do it without those techniques as well). However, the proof sketch I came up with required this result.

Comment: I'm skeptical. Don't you need to be in a model category (or 2-category) of *cocomplete* dg-categories for these tensor products to even make sense? In this context the question makes more sense, but then you also need to specify what the model structure is.

Comment: @ReidBarton Toën claims on page 10 of the paper I mentioned that Tabuada has shown that there is a model structure on $\mathsf{dgCat}$ with fibrations as defined above and whose weak equivalences are the quasi-equivalences. In section 4, Toën defines the tensor and derived tensor product of two dg-categories by $C\otimes^L D:=Q(C)\otimes D,$ where $Q:\mathsf{dgCat}\to\mathsf{dgCat}$ is a cofibrant replacement functor for this model structure which acts as the identity on objects. Perhaps I'm missing something, but nowhere have I seen a requirement that the dg-categories be cocomplete.

Comment: @Stahl: For your cited fact, I suggest to observe first that dgCat_C is homotopy cocontinuous in C.  Then the problem for dg-algebras reduces to the case C=D=k, the base ring, which can be shown directly.  Nothing in this argument needs ∞-categories.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thanks for all your help here. I'll follow the outline you've provided!

Comment: The tensor product in section 4 does not correspond to the tensor product of presentable ∞-categories which appears in formulas like $\mathsf{dgMod}_C \otimes^L \mathsf{dgMod}_D = \mathsf{dgMod}_{C \otimes^L D}$. It is closer to the ordinary product of categories. A general $C \otimes^L D$-module isn't built out of a $C$-module and a $D$-module; you need to allow formation of colimits as well.

Comment: Or more simply, $\mathsf{dgMod}_C$ *as an object of $\mathsf{dgCat}$* doesn't commute with colimits in $C$ in any sense because, for example, if $C$ is the initial dg-category, $\mathsf{dgMod}_C$ is not *empty*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: suppose that C is a cofibrant dg-category. Then are either of Ĉ or dgMod_C^op cofibrant dg-categories?

A cofibrant object in a cofibrantly generated model category (such as dgCat)
is a retract of a transfinite composition of cobase changes of generating cofibrations.
Generating cofibrations of dgCat are functors between small categories
(see, for example, (4.7) and (4.13) in [arXiv:1201.1575](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.1575)),
and cobase change, transfinite composition, and retracts preserve this property.
Since dgMod_C^op and Ĉ both have a proper class of objects
(and even a proper class of weak equivalence classes of objects),
there is no way dgMod_C^op or Ĉ could be made into cofibrant dg-categories.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for your answer! I didn't expect set-theoretic issues to get in the way, but perhaps I should have given that Toën is intentionally making use of universe-changing in the paper. It sounds like I might be able to get what I want if I play with changing universes like Toën does, but I'll have to think about this a bit more. By the way, do you know of a reference where I might find the proof that generating cofibrations of $\mathsf{dgCat}$ are functors between small categories?

Comment: @Stahl: Generating cofibrations are functors between categories with 0, 1, or 2 objects, I added a reference to the answer.

Comment: @Stahl: There are other problems apart from size issues, e.g., cofibrant dg-categories are (roughly) retracts of free dg-categories, and this imposes an obstruction that one can show is violated for dg-categories of modules over simplest dg-categories, e.g., dg-modules over an ordinary ring.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I'm a little confused by your last comment, though: suppose I fix a Grothendieck universe $\Bbb{U},$ and fix $C\in\mathsf{dgCat}_{\Bbb{U}}$ (cofibrant, although this now seems irrelevant). Then I can form the category $\mathsf{dgMod}_{C,\Bbb{U}}$ of dg-modules over $C$ in $\mathsf{dgCat}_{\Bbb{U}}$ which as you've stated is not cofibrant in $\mathsf{dgCat}_{\Bbb{U}}.$

Comment: However, it then seems like if I choose an appropriate universe $\Bbb{V}\ni\Bbb{U},$ and consider $\mathsf{dgMod}_{C,\Bbb{U}}$ inside $\mathsf{dgCat}_{\Bbb{V}},$ it should now be cofibrant in $\mathsf{dgCat}_{\Bbb{V}}$: it is now small, and so the functor to the terminal object should be a cofibration by the results you've cited. What am I missing?

Comment: @Stahl: I do not understand your last sentence: "so the functor to the terminal object should be a cofibration by the results you've cited": for cofibrancy, one needs the functor from the initial object to be a cofibration, and how does it follow from the cited results?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the variance. In either case, if the generating cofibrations are functors between small categories, then working inside $\mathsf{dgCat}_{\Bbb{V}}$ (choosing a universe $\Bbb{V}$ in which the objects and morphisms of $\mathsf{dgMod}_{C,\Bbb{U}}$ form sets) we should have that $\emptyset\to \mathsf{dgMod}_{C,\Bbb{U}}$ would be one of the generating cofibrations in $\mathsf{dgCat}_{\Bbb{V}},$ as in $\Bbb{V}$ both $\mathsf{dgMod}_{C,\Bbb{U}}$ and the initial dg-category $\emptyset$ are small.

Comment: @Stahl: All generating cofibrations are functors between small (in fact, finite) categories, but not all functors between small (or finite) categories are generating cofibrations.  The inclusion is in one direction only.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the statement you made. Thanks for the clarification!